# Yarn ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

This is just to document this error and its solution for us, as I have seen several people having it but not found a solution for it on the web.

So the Nodemanager failed to start, which could be easily seen in the logs as a

```
ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler
```

when one tries to start it manually using the command:

```
 yarn nodemanager
```

Answer (score 0):

So the classpath showed that the mapreduce directory wasn't correctly set in the classpath. In fact, it was /opt/hadoop-2.9.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/* which isn't a correct classpath. the * character wasn't interpolated.
So this led us to look at the HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME environment variable.
It was incorrectly set, as it must be equal to HADOOP_HOME.